# How do I clone a Django model instance object and save it to the database?

Tags: python, django, django-models

```
Foo.objects.get(pk="foo")
<Foo: test>
```

In the database, I want to add another object which is a copy of the object above.

Suppose my table has one row. I want to insert the first row object into another row with a different primary key. How can I do that?

Answer (score 651, accepted):

Just change the primary key of your object and run save().

```
obj = Foo.objects.get(pk=<some_existing_pk>)
obj.pk = None
obj.save()
```

If you want auto-generated key, set the new key to None.

More on UPDATE/INSERT [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#how-django-knows-to-update-vs-insert).

Official docs on copying model instances: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#copying-model-instances

Comment: Worth noting that this quotes Django 1.2, we're now up to Django 1.4. Haven't tested whether or not this works, but don't use this answer without being sure that it works for you.

Comment: Works fine in 1.4.1 This is probably one of those things that will continue to work for a long while.

Comment: this is not a general solution for when you have a database with automatic primary keys... guessing at an unused primary key seems like a bad idea.

Comment: I had to set both `obj.pk` and `obj.id` to make this work in Django 1.4

Comment: @PetrPeller - the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#copying-model-instances) suggest that's because you're using model inheritance .

Comment: I prefer the solution from @S. Kirby - you should never start setting pks manually

Comment: Note: things may be a bit more complex if there are foreign keys, one2one's and m2m's involved (i.e., there may be more complex "deep copy" scenarios)

Comment: if there is a `datetime` field it will change

Comment: This method only works if you don't intend to use the original object after making the copy.

Comment: this doesn't copy over the relationships of models towrads the instance aka related fields

Comment: What if model have other unique fields than id? How would you copy in that case without setting them to None in hard coded way?

Comment: @miah, how do you get the newly created object after that?

Comment: What if I want to copy say 500 instances (an entire queryset)? Looping over it is slow so wondering if I can somehow use bulk_create?

Comment: This is expensive in that in incurs in a database call.
It also doesn't clone the object, but the database entry itself (the in-memory one is the same as the original, and they'll mutate together).

Comment: I haven't seen that mentioned, but you might (or might not) want to add obj._state.adding = True before saving, depending on if you want it to act like a brand new object or an already existing one. It might have (or might not) impact on your save() calls and so on.

Comment: This creates an error for me, presumably because both objects are pointing to the same momory location??

Answer (score 167):

The Django documentation for database queries includes [a section on copying model instances](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/queries/#copying-model-instances).  Assuming your primary keys are autogenerated, you get the object you want to copy, set the primary key to `None`, and save the object again:

```
blog = Blog(name='My blog', tagline='Blogging is easy')
blog.save() # blog.pk == 1

blog.pk = None
blog.save() # blog.pk == 2
```

In this snippet, the first `save()` creates the original object, and the second `save()` creates the copy.

If you keep reading the documentation, there are also examples on how to handle two more complex cases: (1) copying an object which is an instance of a model subclass, and (2) also copying related objects, including objects in many-to-many relations.

---

Note on miah's answer: Setting the pk to `None` is mentioned in miah's answer, although it's not presented front and center. So my answer mainly serves to emphasize that method as the Django-recommended way to do it.

Historical note: This wasn't explained in the Django docs until version 1.4. It has been possible since before 1.4, though.

Possible future functionality: The aforementioned docs change was made in [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/4027). On the ticket's comment thread, there was also some discussion on adding a built-in `copy` function for model classes, but as far as I know they decided not to tackle that problem yet.  So this "manual" way of copying will probably have to do for now.

Answer (score 64):

Be careful here.  This can be extremely expensive if you're in a loop of some kind and you're retrieving objects one by one.  If you don't want the call to the database, just do:

```
from copy import deepcopy

new_instance = deepcopy(object_you_want_copied)
new_instance.id = None
new_instance.save()
```

It does the same thing as some of these other answers, but it doesn't make the database call to retrieve an object.  This is also useful if you want to make a copy of an object that doesn't exist yet in the database.

Comment: This works great if you have an object, you can deep copy the original object before making changes make changes to the new object and save it. Then you can do some condition checking and depending on if they pass, i.e. the object is in another table that you are checking, you can set the new_instance.id = original_instance.id and save :) Thanks!

Comment: This does not work if the model has multiple inheritance levels.

Comment: on my case I wanted to create a clone method for the model, which would use the "self" variable and I cannot simply just set the self.pk None, so this solution worked like a charm. I thought about the model_to_dict solution below, but it requires an extra step and it would have the same issue with the through relations, which I have to deal manually anyway so it has no major impact for me.

Answer (score 54):

Use the below code :

```
from django.forms import model_to_dict

instance = Some.objects.get(slug='something')

kwargs = model_to_dict(instance, exclude=['id'])
new_instance = Some.objects.create(**kwargs)
```

Comment: `model_to_dict` takes an `exclude` parameter, which means you don't need the separate `pop`: `model_to_dict(instance, exclude=['id'])`

Comment: this will cause an exception with foreign keys

Answer (score 23):

There's a clone snippet [here](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/904/), which you can add to your model which does this:

```
def clone(self):
  new_kwargs = dict([(fld.name, getattr(old, fld.name)) for fld in old._meta.fields if fld.name != old._meta.pk]);
  return self.__class__.objects.create(**new_kwargs)
```

Comment: @user426975 - ah, oh well (I've removed it from my answer).

Comment: Not sure if this is a Django version thing, but the `if` now needs to be `if fld.name != old._meta.pk.name`, ie, the `name` property of the `_meta.pk` instance.

Answer (score 22):

How to do this was added to the official Django docs in Django1.4

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#copying-model-instances

The official answer is similar to miah's answer, but the docs point out some difficulties with  inheritance and related objects, so you should probably make sure you read the docs.

Comment: when you open the link it says page not found

Comment: The docs no longer exist for Django 1.4. I'll update the answer to point to the latest docs.

Comment: @MichaelBylstra A good way to have evergreen links is to use `stable` instead of the version number in the URL, like this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/queries/#copying-model-instances

Answer (score 13):

I've run into a couple gotchas with the accepted answer. Here is my solution.

```
import copy

def clone(instance):
    cloned = copy.copy(instance) # don't alter original instance
    cloned.pk = None
    try:
        delattr(cloned, '_prefetched_objects_cache')
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    return cloned
```

Note: this uses solutions that aren't officially sanctioned in the Django docs, and they may cease to work in future versions. I tested this in 1.9.13.

The first improvement is that it allows you to continue using the original instance, by using `copy.copy`. Even if you don't intend to reuse the instance, it can be safer to do this step if the instance you're cloning was passed as an argument to a function. If not, the caller will unexpectedly have a different instance when the function returns.

`copy.copy` seems to produce a shallow copy of a Django model instance in the desired way. This is one of the things I did not find documented, but it works by pickling and unpickling, so it's probably well-supported.

Secondly, the approved answer will leave any prefetched results attached to the new instance. Those results shouldn't be associated with the new instance, unless you explicitly copy the to-many relationships. If you traverse the the prefetched relationships, you will get results that don't match the database. Breaking working code when you add a prefetch can be a nasty surprise.

Deleting `_prefetched_objects_cache` is a quick-and-dirty way to strip away all prefetches. Subsequent to-many accesses work as if there never was a prefetch. Using an undocumented property that begins with an underscore is probably asking for compatibility trouble, but it works for now.

Comment: I was able to get this to work, but it looks like it may have already changed in 1.11, as I had a property called `_[model_name]_cache`, which, once deleted, i was able to assign a new ID for that related model, then call `save()`.  There still could be side effects I haven't determined yet.

Comment: This is extremely important info if you are doing the cloning in a function on the class/mixin, as it will otherwise mess up 'self' and you'll get all confused.

Comment: very useful if you plan to use the original object further in the code. II went crazy for 2 hours trying to figure out why my next query with the original subject gave zero results.

Answer (score 7):

This is yet another way of cloning the model instance:

```
d = Foo.objects.filter(pk=1).values().first()   
d.update({'id': None})
duplicate = Foo.objects.create(**d)
```

Answer (score 5):

setting pk to None is better, sinse Django can correctly create a pk for you

```
object_copy = MyObject.objects.get(pk=...)
object_copy.pk = None
object_copy.save()
```

Answer (score 3):

This does an in-memory copy that you can mutate independently.

```py
original = CheckoutItem(title="test", ...)
copy = CheckoutItem()

for f in CheckoutItem._meta.fields:
   setattr(copy, f.attname, getattr(original, f.attname))
```

Or, as a method:

```
    def clone(self):
        """Returns a clone of this instance."""

        clone = self.__class__()
        for f in self.__class__._meta.fields:
            setattr(clone, f.attname, getattr(self, f.attname))

        return clone
```

Comment: This does not work as intended since it copies the `pk` and `id` as well, saving the clone will effectively update the cloned object.

Comment: Indeed, the clone will be identical. If you want to save it as a _new_ instance, then just set `clone.pk = None`. (I recommend using `pk` instead of `id` in case the primary key is some other field, e.g.: `uuid`).

Comment: does it work for Foreign Key and ManyToMany field ?

Comment: @SandeepBalagopal I'm not entirely sure (I encourage you to try and confirm this), but I think it that the clone would simply have `ForeignKey`s pointing to the same instances as the original.

Answer (score 0):

To clone a model with multiple inheritance levels, i.e. >= 2, or ModelC below

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    info1 = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class ModelB(ModelA):
    info2 = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class ModelC(ModelB):
    info3 = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Please refer the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15907091/clone-an-inherited-django-model-instance).

Comment: Ah yes, but that question doesn't have an accepted answer! Way to go!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
original_object = Foo.objects.get(pk="foo")
v = vars(original_object)
v.pop("pk")
new_object = Foo(**v)
new_object.save()
```

Comment: Somewhat pointless to pop the pk attribute. Setting to None makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

There is a package that can do this which creates a UI within the django admin site: https://github.com/RealGeeks/django-modelclone

```
pip install django-modelclone
```

Add "modelclone" to INSTALLED_APPS and import it within admin.py.

Then, whenever you want to make a model clonable, you just replace "admin.ModelAdmin" in the given admin model class "modelclone.ClonableModelAdmin". This results in a "Duplicate" button appearing within the instance details page for that given model.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `OneToOneField` then you should do it this way:

```
    tmp = Foo.objects.get(pk=1)
    tmp.pk = None
    tmp.id = None
    instance = tmp
```

Comment: Can you expand on why this is necessary for a OneToOneField? Where is the OneToOneField (i.e. which model points to which)?

Answer (score 0):

This simple process works fine for me:

```
foo_obj = Foo.objects.get(pk="foo")
foo_values = foo_obj.__dict__
foo_values.pop('_state')
foo_values.pop('id')
foo_new_obj = Foo(**foo_values)
foo_new_obj.save()
```

Comment: minus this solution there is no way to get related many to many when overriding the method