# Clone an inherited django model instance

Tags: python, django, django-models

When I clone a django model instance I used to clean the 'pk' field.
This seems not to work with an inherited model :

Take this :

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    info1 = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class ModelB(ModelA):
    info2 = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class ModelC(ModelB):
    info3 = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Now let's create an instance and clone it by the 'usual' way ( I am using a django shell ):

```
In [1]: c=ModelC(info1="aaa",info2="bbb",info3="ccc")

In [2]: c.save()

In [3]: c.pk
Out[3]: 1L

In [4]: c.pk=None  <------ to clone

In [5]: c.save()   <------ should generate a new instance with a new index key

In [6]: c.pk       
Out[6]: 1L         <------ but don't

In [7]: ModelC.objects.all()
Out[7]: [<ModelC: ModelC object>]   (only one instance !)
```

The only way I found was to do :

```
In [16]: c.pk =None

In [17]: c.id=None

In [21]: c.modela_ptr_id=None

In [22]: c.modelb_ptr_id=None

In [23]: c.save()

In [24]: c.pk
Out[24]: 2L    <---- successful clone containing info1,info2,info3 from original instance

In [25]: ModelC.objects.all()
Out[25]: [<ModelC: ModelC object>, <ModelC: ModelC object>]
```

I find that very ugly, is there a more nice way to clone an instance from an inherited model ?

Comment: Will you be using the base models by themselves at all or will you only be using the model that inherits from them?  If you don't need to use the base models by themselves, then it should work to use [abstract base classes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes).

Comment: Actually inheritance in Django models can be considered a bad practice, you can use abstract base classes, or Foreign Keys.

Comment: Can you please paste you save() method, how are you setting the pk on the model ?

Comment: Actually, in my program, I have several inheritence levels, the 2 first levels are abstract, then I have 2 other levels bringing their own parameters. I planned to have one more, that's why I made this example. When I see tables generated, for that, I may go back to a more 'usual' model pattern : only one non-abstract model level.

Comment: I am using polymorphic models, setting basemodel_ptr_id to None doesnt create new records for me, except it works if I set id to None as well like what you showed.

Answer (score 1):

I was puzzled by Django's behavior in the scenario you posited, so I put in a bunch of `print` statements down in Django's [models\base.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/4.2.x/django/db/models/base.py) file to figure out what was going on. It turns out that, in the inheritance example you set up, `ModelC` effectively has more than one primary key. There's even [a comment](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/4.2.x/django/db/models/base.py#L1332) down in the code itself that references this subtle behavior (see related Django [ticket 17615](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17615)).

The crux of the matter is that non-abstract model inheritance works through `OneToOneField` relationships, which are a special variant of `ForeignKey`. So `ModelC` in your example ends up with two `OneToOneField` relationships: one concrete key (`modelb_ptr_id`) and one inherited key via ModelB (`modela_ptr_id`). The `id` attribute may also be considered a primary key, but I think it's conceptually just an alias for `modela_ptr_id` under the hood.

When you set the `ModelC` instance pk value to 0, you are effectively clearing the "first" (closest binding) primary key. But there's another primary key in play! The Django `save()` routine calls an internal [_save_parents()](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/4.2.x/django/db/models/base.py#L903) method which does a sync between the keys if they don't match. It does this by recursively walking up the parent relationships, syncing items as it goes. This routine is where the `ModelC` instance primary key gets "reset" to 1 in your initial example. The routine walks up `ModelC` to `ModelB`, sees that it has a parent (and that the parent value does not match the current value), syncs the two, and continues.

If I understand the code correctly, this routine is in place to ensure that all parents have been written to the database as necessary, so that there is no data loss as items get saved. This is subtle behavior, but something worth paying attention to in inheritance usage.

This was a very interesting question!

Answer (score 0):

```
c=ModelC(info1="aaa",info2="bbb",info3="ccc")
# creates an instance

c.save()
# writes instance to db

c.pk=None
# I doubt u can nullify the auto-generated pk of an existing object, because a pk is not nullable
c.save()
# if I'm right nothing will happen here.
```

So c will always be the same object. If you want to clone it you need to generate a new object. Either with a constructor within ModelC:

```
def __init__(another_modelC_obj=null, self):
   if another_modelC_obj:
      # for every field in another_modelC_obj: do self.field = another_modelC_obj.field
   super().__init__()
```

so you can go

```
c2=ModelC(c)
```

Or call it directly with:

```
c2=ModelC(c.info1, c.info2, c.info3)
```

Then c2 and c will be identical despite of their pk

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to `save()` it again immediately after setting `c.pk = None`.

Why?
Because the `ModelC.id` field is an auto-generated and auto-incremented field.

When you call `save()`, Django treats the instance as new, and the database will assign a unique primary key value.

```py
# old id / pk
print(c.id)

# set it null
c.pk = None

# ask Django to save it again
c.save()

#get new id
print(c.id)
```

2. Be mindful of other many-to-many or foreign keys in your model, as these relationships will also be copied.
3. If this is a common requirement for your models, consider creating an abstract class for this purpose.

```py
from django.db import models

class CloneableModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def clone(self):
        new_instance = self.__class__().get(id=self.id)
        new_instance.id = None
        new_instance.save()

        return new_instance

class ModelC(CloneableModel):
...
```