# Insert multiple rows in one operation by cloning a queryset with only one column change in Django

Tags: django

I have seen the following link:
[How do I clone a Django model instance object and save it to the database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733609/how-do-i-clone-a-django-model-instance-object-and-save-it-to-the-database)

But this one does only 1 object cloning. What if I want to clone multiple objects cloned.
For eg. something like this:

```
foo_objects = Foo.objects.filter(col1=value1)
foo_objects.pk = None
foo_objects.col2=value2
foo_objects.save()
```

I know I can use bulk insert. Please suggest another method if any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no update method on queryset that can update relationship fields. You would have to either use `bulk_create()` to create/save multiple objects. But before that iterate through queryset to set attributes appropriately.

Something like

```
foo_objects = Foo.objects.filter(col1=value1)
for f in foo_objects:
    f.pk = None
    f.col2=value2
    f.save() #either do this or save with bulk create as

Foo.objects.bulk_create(foo_objects)
```

Comment: This is what I also came up to. I didn't want to create full objects. I have used bulk_create finally.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use bulk create, you can control transaction commit by your own like this

```
from django.db import transaction

with transaction.commit_on_success():
        for foo_object in foo_objects:
            foo_object.pk = None
            foo_objects.col2=value2
            foo_objects.save()
```