# Create new model instances from existing ones

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    fieldA = models.IntegerField()
    fieldB = models.IntegerField()
    fieldC = models.IntegerField()
```

Now, let's get a QuerySet, e.g.

```
qs = MyModel.objects.all()
```

I'd like to be able to change `fieldB` and `fieldC` of all instances in `qs` with the same value and save them as NEW records in my database. I need something similar to `qs.update(fieldB=2, fieldC=3)` but I don't want to override the original records in `qs`. Is there a Django-way to do so (i.e., something not involving a manually coded `for` loop)?

Comment: Not sure how I mark duplicate (new to this site), but your answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733609/how-do-i-clone-a-django-model-instance-object-and-save-it-to-the-database

Comment: Thanks, but that applies to a single instance, is there a way to do it for all instances? (again, something other than the usual `for` loop, possibly something that insert all records with a single query).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of a Django call that will do what you want in a single call, like `update` does.

This is the closest I've been able to come to. Assuming that the objects you wanted to operate on are in `qs` then:

```py
MyModel.objects.bulk_create(
    MyModel(**{pair[0]: pair[1] for pair in x.iteritems() 
                if pair[0] != MyModel._meta.pk.name}) 
     for x in qs.values())
```

Notes:

1. `qs.values()` returns one dictionary per object in `qs`.
2. The `{pair[0]...}` expression is a dictionary comprehension that creates a new dictionary minus primary field defined on `MyModel`.
3. `MyModel(**...)` creates a new `MyModel` object with its primary key set to `None`. It effectively creates a copy.
4. `bulk_create` creates all the objects in one query. It has [caveats](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) that one should be aware of.

If it needs be mentioned, what you have here are dict and list comprehensions, not `for` loops.