# How can I save the same form more than once in Django 1.8?

Tags: python, django

I have a model Product and a corresponding form Product and I need to update the stock with lets say 5 product, so I input the data for the Product and ask how many items of this product I want to store, because all products to save are the same, except for Django default ID, i was thinking of doing something like this in the view:

```
for i in range(0, 5):
   form.save()
```

Unfortunately this only saves the last form.

How else can I achieve what I need?

Comment: Save one, then [create clones of the one from the form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733609/how-do-i-clone-a-django-model-instance-object-and-save-it-to-the-database)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Calling save with `commit=False` returns an instance that is not saved to the database.

```
instance = form.save(commit=False)
```

You can the save the instance multiple times in a loop. By setting the primary key to None, a new object will be saved each time.

```
for i in range(0, 5):
    instance.pk = None
    instance.save()
```

Comment: thanks all i needed to do was put primary key to None. Thanks Much Appreciated.