# Looping insert data to database with django

Tags: python, django

can insert loop data into django model?..

here my code. on `view.py`

```
    class EmpCreateView(CreateView):
        fields = ()
        model = models.Employee

        def form_valid(self, form):
            self.object = form.save(commit=False)

            loopdo = 5
            while loopdo > 0:
                self.object.name = "work?" 
                self.object.no = loopdo
                self.object.save()
                loopdo -= 1

            return super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)
```

it's only insert 1 data.

Comment: Could it be that your data model doesn't allow some of the data taken from the form to be duplicated (unique = true) ? That way most of the insertions would fail since you can't have, for example, the same name twice.

Comment: Don't use loop for save multiple objects, use bulk_create.. it is an advice only

Comment: @BurakÖztürk bulk create can use data from another model?...

Comment: I get **super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try setting the primary key to None.

See this answer: [How can I save the same form more than once in Django 1.8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33027011/how-can-i-save-the-same-form-more-than-once-in-django-1-8)

I got my reference from: [Save multiple data using loops in django models using save function with admin save button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45293833/save-multiple-data-using-loops-in-django-models-using-save-function-with-admin-s)

Comment: Awesome! :). When you get a chance, can you accept the answer? It helps other users know the question is answered and also my rating!

Comment: Why are we not advising a formset here?