# Why does the original django object get changed when cloning?

Tags: python, django

I want to clone a django model/object. Here is my code with some debugging statements (method is inside my Item class)

```
def duplicate_item(self):
    print("original",self.id)
    copy = self
    copy.id = uuid.uuid4()
    print("copy",copy.id)
    copy.save()
    print("What happened",self.id)
```

This was the output:

```
original 6a5a8d54-5b45-47fd-abf3-4357aa89dd0c
copy 5b6bfb5f-36b2-4a74-968e-c1f007df9056
what happened 5b6bfb5f-36b2-4a74-968e-c1f007df9056
```

Why does this happen? I don't know enough about python shallow/deep copy logic so that probably has to do with it. Thank you

Comment: You are not cloning anything, you just assign the same object an alternative name. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733609/how-do-i-clone-a-django-model-instance-object-and-save-it-to-the-database) about cloning Django model instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @selcuk says, here *"you are not cloning anything"*. You can use this method to clone your object.

> **Note:** you can change this `pk` as `id` if your primary key is `id`

```
def duplicate_item(self):
    old_data = self.__dict__

    if 'pk' in old_data:
        del old_data['pk']

    if '_state' in old_data:
        del old_data['_state']

    new_object = self.__class__.objects.create(**old_data)
    return new_object
```

But also you can modify your `pk/id` by using `uuid.uuid4()`

```
def duplicate_item(self):
    old_data = self.__dict__
    old_data['pk'] = uuid.uuid4() # new id

    if '_state' in old_data:
        del old_data['_state']

    new_object = self.__class__.objects.create(**old_data)
    return new_object
```