# How to clone a model instance without cloning database relationship?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm building a cart model with the following code.

```
from django.db import models

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Order(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    transcation_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date)

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
```

The many-to-one relationship between `Item` and `Order` allows one `Order` to contain many `Item` and that looks fine.

A model instance can be simply cloned as already answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733609/how-do-i-clone-a-django-model-instance-object-and-save-it-to-the-database).

My problem is, if the `price` of an `Item` is changed. The price of contained items in Order is change too. But I don't want it to be changed. In the situation that customer already make a purchase, the price cannot be change. Is there anyway to clone the `Order` instance that completely not related to the other model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the price manually

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    price = price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, null=True, default=None)
    def save():
        if self.pk == None:
            self.price = self.item.price
            super(OrderItem, self).save()
```

Comment: It's error. Exception Value: save() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given.

Comment: add a self there

def save(self):

Comment: Exception Value: name 'item' is not defined

Comment: self.price = self.item.price

Comment: Thank you so much. There is a bit editing needed. `super(OrderItem, self).save()`